# Since installing an SSL certificate the featured images from my portfolio aren't displaying on my website homepage

Tags: ssl-certificate, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress for my website with a Phlox theme and the Elementor and Phlox plug-ins. Since installing the SSL certificate the feature images are not displaying on [my home page](http://helenbradbury.co.uk). The area it should be is blank however the filters are displaying and if you hover over the text is there (it's just white on white). The feature images are on `https://`.

I know it's due to the SSL certificate as before it was redirecting properly they displayed on `http://` but not `https://`.

I've checked it's all set up correctly hosting side, which it is (and spoken to the host company). I've installed Really Simple SSL and followed their steps including doing this — [How to fix mixed content in Elementor after moving to SSL](https://really-simple-ssl.com/knowledge-base/how-to-fix-mixed-content-in-elementor-after-moving-to-ssl/)

If I go into Elementor > System info it does say this

> There are some writing permissions issues with the following directories/files: - WordPress root uploads directory

so I don't know if it's something to do with this. I asked the hosting company and they tried to fix it but it didn't. There don't appear to be any other error messages.

Comment: Note that the Stack Exchange network also has a dedicated website for Wordpress at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thanks @Anaksunaman. I've just asked on there too.